# Which is the Purana Brihat Samhita depicted in?

Tags: puranas

In which Purana, Brihat Samhita finds a place? What does this depict?

Comment: It is an work on Astrology by Varahamihira and so NOT part of any Purana.

Answer (score 5):

[**Brihat Samhita**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brihat-samhita) (वृहत्संहिता) is a work of [Varāhamihira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Var%C4%81hamihira), a well known polymath and astronomer lived around 5<sup>th</sup>-6<sup>th</sup> century. His most notable three works are

1. Brihat Jaataka
2. Brihat Samhita
3. Pancha-Siddhantika

You can get Brihat Samhita Sanskrit verse with English translation from Internet Archive.

> [image]

[Puranas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puranas), on other hand are written by [Vedavyasa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vyasa) (who is an 'Avatara' of Vishnu) in the Dwapara Yuga and forms important class in Hindu texts.

Since Brihat Samhita by Varahamihira is a work later to Puranas, it is obvious that Puranas wouldn't include (or even mention) Brihat Samhita. In other words, **Brihat Samhita is not a part of Purana.**